# How do I exclude a dependency of Microsoft.NETCore.APP

Tags: c#, .net-core, csproj, packagereference

How do I exclude a dependency of Microsoft.NETCore.App so I can replace it with a locally compiled (bugfix) version.

I carried out the normal procedure for replacing a package by making one with a higher version number, and tried to compile. The build tried to link against *both* and died at the compile step with CS0433 due to duplicate references.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
       <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
       <ProjectReference Include="..\System.Threading.ThreadPool\System.Threading.ThreadPool.csproj"/>
       <ProjectReference Update="..\System.Threading.ThreadPool\System.Threading.ThreadPool.csproj"/>
   </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Compile error:

> C:\Program FFiles\dotnet\sdk\2.1.604\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2114,5): warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between "System.Threading.ThreadPool, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" and "System.Threading.ThreadPool, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTokn=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Threading.ThreadPool, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" arbitrarily. [path]
>
> Program.cs(17,13): error CS0433: The type 'ThreadPool' exists in both 'System.Threading.ThreadPool, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Threading.ThreadPool, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' [path]

Answer (score 1):

I assume you compiled corefx to produce the updated System.Threading.ThreadPool package?

In that case [corefx has docs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/dogfooding.md#more-advanced-scenario---using-your-local-corefx-build) that spell out how do this. To summarize:

1. Build corefx with your fixes
2. Get the version number of the corefx that you built
3. Add a PackageReference to `Microsoft.Private.CoreFx.NETCoreApp` with the version from step 2
4. Add a nuget.config that points to the bin directory of the corefx that you built.
5. restore and publish your project to pick up the custom-modified corefx.

Comment: No, I did not build a new corefx. I built a Visual Studio project that spits out a de novo reimplementation of the dll to replace.